# How is a Segmentation Fault Thrown?

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault

What determines a segmentation fault and how is the signal sent?
Specifically, in Ubuntu or any Linux OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This section](http://book.opensourceproject.org.cn/kernel/kernelpri/index.html?page=opensource/0131181637/ch04lev1sec10.html) of the Linux Kernel Primer provides a detailed description both of the architecture-specific details of how segmentation faults are detected on the x86 architecture and of how they are then handled in Linux.

Comment: @BoltClock: Unfortunately, the book no longer appears to be available on the website I linked to. I've Googled, and there appear to be a number of websites that offer free downloads of the book, but I'm not sure whether they're legal, so I'm hesitant to link to them.